# posting data with apostrophe

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a complete beginner at `PHP` but have managed a simple code to input data to a table.

The code is:

```
$query = "INSERT into $table (suggestion1) VALUES('$suggestion1')";
```

All works fine but if the data inserted contains an apostrophe (e.g. don't) the query fails.

I've searched for hours but the answers I get are beyond my knowledge.
Any help or pointers would be great!

Steven

Comment: You should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/orrj0) and use either [PDO](http://goo.gl/TD3xh) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/YXyWL) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/b2ATO). Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/J5jAo)

Answer (score 2):

What you should be looking are prepared statements, in which to write your queries with parameters, and the call that prepared statement passing in parameters values and let the driver make the replaces/escaping. [Here's a good starting point using mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Here's a simplified code sample from PHP.net :

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");

/* Prepared statement, stage 1: prepare */
if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO test(id) VALUES (?)"))) {
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}

/* Prepared statement, stage 2: bind and execute */
$id = 1;
if (!$stmt->bind_param("i", $id)) {
    echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to escape your input: check the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

Basically, what happens is this: when you put that data in with quotes, you get this:

```
  INSERT INTO $table (suggestion1) VALUES ('it's great');
```

and MySQL gets confused with the second quote. When you "escape" you get this:

```
  INSERT INTO $table (suggestion1) VALUES ('it\'s great');
```

and MySQL knows that second quote is part of the data, not of the query.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) has info on it as well (a little more extensive, but worth reading and understanding).